# Any class member function type

Tags: c++, c++17

**What is my end goal?**

I would like the user of my library to be able to specify the map of arbitrary field names and member function pointers associated to those field names. An example would be the following:

```cpp
class Foo {
private:
    int field_1_;
    double field_2_;

public:
    int field_1() const { return field_1_; }
    double field_2() const { return field_2_; }
};

std::map<std::string, any_mem_fn> fields = {
    { "field_1", &Foo::field_1 },
    { "field_2", &Foo::field_2 }
};
```

As you might see, the problem is that the member function signatures can be different.

**What I have tried?**

I tried creating `any_mem_fn` class which stores any member function pointer. Class looks like the following:

```cpp
class any_mem_fn {
    struct base_mem_fn_ptr {
        virtual ~base_mem_fn_ptr() {}
        virtual double operator()(Foo& foo) = 0;
    };

    template <typename F>
    struct mem_fn_ptr : base_mem_fn_ptr {
        F fn;

        mem_fn_ptr(F&& f)
            : fn(std::forward<F>(f))
        {}

        double operator()(Foo& foo) override {
            return std::invoke(fn, foo);
        }
    };

public:
    any_mem_fn() : fn_(nullptr) {}
    any_mem_fn(any_mem_fn&& rhs) = default;
    any_mem_fn(any_mem_fn const& rhs) = default;

    template <typename F>
    any_mem_fn(F&& f) {
        fn_ = std::make_shared<mem_fn_ptr<F>>(std::forward<F>(f));
    }

    any_mem_fn& operator=(any_mem_fn&& rhs) = default;
    any_mem_fn& operator=(any_mem_fn const& rhs) = default;

    ~any_mem_fn() = default;

    template <typename T>
    double value(T&& obj) {
        return std::invoke(*fn_, obj);
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<base_mem_fn_ptr> fn_;
};
```

Here, as you can see, I used polymorphism for type erasure. Furthermore, you might notice that `operator()` in case of every function signature returns `double`. This is **intentional** and not my problem currently so please don't refer to this.

Now, what is the problem with the above class... The problem is that it only works for the member functions of a `Foo` class. If I try to store member function of a `Bar` class, code above won't work. In order to make the above code work in case of any class, I would need to overload `operator()` for each specific class which I cannot do because my library is not aware of all the classes that user of library has.

Full demo is [here](https://godbolt.org/#z: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%2Bww9h4/Ntttjt9G%2BxtGXiDNdAgEA0YgAO75OgbzLoI2DUH0r5FoOaqFja74wuWRiVicNZ1g2VLNmCz6dqiqBxp4xB4K8aowYh%2BrEEy36/o4caoAA1pg1C0KQHZgq%2Bw7kTC6pFkOQp3AEKGsHgyAgCaYgune%2BbojmEC0EYrCsMeuq8ausKSVmobYs6Wmek%2B0jtsQCBKN2vZYFQzCKQQA4abp0maXecxoLQzTPsZpmnOZmCWdZ16juOk4nG8s7zouIIrsSjkhp6j6GbhqncZeGJeXMNEgCYzBMRiSgIPkmAgUsd47qBtzgV%2BBA/n%2BJBAcQhV6GBEFUFBtk8fBEn2TFV6GdWtbEPWJCLPiOlSV1BlGSZZlzBZVmsDZXHqTC0XZt17bof1DZDSNelMi5bk9R5U0zX5C0mqmy3aUdPmzfNAkBSYE71sFSyhTo4UACqRbCyGoXMcZsEYzGffFPWoG4fCJYtsaUdRlW0bQ9FMRAABUOZsWDEOtcafz7AExH/WO4lFuluX5egJVLPuO0U9gyXXlap37KSmWOPmp5Fi2HacBAnCcT6sKc1Q0gQNIfMmgA9OLMpzG43O81jF2epe3Nti2v7amLRaS4rTKesLbYyurFKawhsLpWgRhIm8bwLNI0gAGoAycnDojI0jTjbnqcAAdP9xjMVQvMe0saVwyAtisFj5tDFbSw227jv%2B3M0iu3bwd6MrvtO9Qovp6HVUR1jkvR5becJ07cyCKn7vWyHetZ/7ECy92eg2%2BlhdGpLcxEYNONQzDfb0/iYwDKwIBjAArGMpDmGMOzT6g4%2Bt3IChpUMIzBQ8gjTwQ4/z1BpAIFcWBeFSpAMSAE87CI4/cNPs/z6Qi9jNPSggNfu9zyPpBwLAMCICgVAD08DsDIBQCAaBgGgJAMAJQC4Ai5VQAQUgVAQFjmIG/Jue9p5uEcPkdY49ODT0gSsegAB5WgrACFf1IFgTK4h2DYNoYmLIGhCJvxoZgAAHlkS24xH6IlUEwkSbh%2BrEHWAYLAhCd7ERMNIgYNB6BMDYBwHg/AuAiDEBIBQCgRB4DcG/SAAwawVA4QAWm/ENKQK85CcAsK/TI2QtAQFsG0cw1hbDdHqF4GIwRQh0DcRo2I/jaBeJSA0awKhyg5BaIUQwxQNFRNYTErojg6jhJ8coWJgTImxLCb0XmgxhijCEKPceU8Z5MOflwgAHN4Mx3huBkmQMgOYEB1y0AYqiCAuBCAkFtoIYQcwDBQM8AMoOy95ByB3tgg%2BF9Bne0GUs5ZKyb5jDvqQORV9Kk0Ofq/d%2BpBP77x/v/CASAY5CWQeAyBAQQERJsPgBsQgUF0EYCwRhaiAL9QCPItZFSH4L3HpMTgcwAKEAQHMWp9TGnNNae04gnwukzK/gfI%2BzAT6UDKes6eWzr4AqfuPfZH9ZkDAvtsseYxt47Mfnsw5JK1nSHvlUwldKUUDEIhgsIIBuBAA%3D%3D%3D).

Library I am working on is [here](https://github.com/m-peko/booleval).

**Question:** Is it somehow possible to store any class member function in a class and be able to invoke that member function later on an object?

Comment: What you describe as a "goal" is a part of a technial solution for a given problem. But I have no idea which problem your code should solve. For me it feels like a XY problem! I can't see any use case, where a map stores all possible member function pointers and objects and call them without knowing the return types. There will be a point in the prog where we have to handle the return type and there we have to know what it represents and which type it has. I believe you running the wrong idea!

Comment: @Klaus if you would like to take a look at my library [here](https://github.com/m-peko/booleval), it might be clearer for you what i want to achieve.

Comment: `std::function<double(std::any)>`?

Comment: Using `std::tuple` instead of `std::map`

Comment: @Jarod42 can you please explain a bit further how would `std::function<double(std::any)>` help?

Comment: from your link, you're basically making an interpreter. you'd likely need to store your `Foo`s and your `Bar`s in a type-erased "value" class that you can work with generically

Comment: @kmdreko I actually have `any_value` class that accepts any type and transforms it to string. That's why I mentioned in the question that returning always a `double` is not a problem because I would replace that `double` with `any_value`

Comment: @Jarod42 regarding the `std::tuple`, it would be great if you could make an answer out of your suggestion

Comment: What should the result be if you try to call `Bar::quux` with a `Foo`?

Comment: @Caleth that should throw an exception. It is expected that one map contains only fields from one class type but, if the user really passes wrong object, then the exception will be thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it is what you want, but with std::function and std::any, you might do something like:

```
class any_mem_fn {
public:
    template <typename Ret, typename C>
    any_mem_fn(Ret (C::*m)()) {
        fn_ = [m](std::any a) { return (std::any_cast<C>(a).*m)(); };
    }
    // Possibly provide overloads for combination const/volatile, reference...

    template <typename T>
    double value(T obj) { return fn_(obj); }

private:
    std::function<double(std::any)> fn_;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7pSMC-)

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you very much!